# Local variable is redundant

Tags: java

I am new to android, can anyone tell me what why is `emailresult` redundant?

[image]

From what I understand is that I retrieve `textToUse` from another method and name it `email` here, and then use `email` to undergo the `matcher.find()` with the result named `emailresult`. I then returned `emailresult` and after that returned the entire `email`.

I have mess around with it some time, like deleting `emailresult` and just use `email`. But then I will still have to create another variable to go under this location:

```
String emailresult = email.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end());
```

Comment: Is `return email.substring(..);` really to abstract to come up with?

Comment: You can just do `return email.substring(matcher.strart(),matcher.end());` and not create the `emailresult` variable.

Comment: Please post actual code instead of screenshots. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Comment: @AnggrayudiH Please avoid adding unrelated tags to the question. This question is _not_ related to android, since it is a question about warning of his IDE about plain Java code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is redundant because you aren't doing anything with `emailresult` after assigning it a value besides returning it. You can simply do the following without the need to create a variable:

```
return email.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end());
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to create a variable

```
return email.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end());
```